# How can I disambiguate '=' symbol in VB.NET, in a lambda function

Tags: vb.net

I am using Dapper to query a flat list of items from a database, into a POCO class as follows:

```
Public Class Node
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property ParentNodeName As String
    Public Property Children As IEnumerable(Of Node)
End Class
```

I am trying to use the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42689413/dapper-build-object-tree-containing-same-object-type), in order to create a tree out of the flat list.

The only caveat is that I am using VB.NET.

I have tried it a straightforward port of the C# solution:

```
nodes.ForEach(Function(n) n.Children = nodes.Where(Function(ch) ch.ParentNodeName = n.Name).ToList)
```

but it does not compile with the error

```
Error   BC30452 Operator '=' is not defined for types 'List(Of Node)' and 'List(Of Node)'.
```

The `=` symbol is interpreted as an equality operator, while I meant to use the assignment operator.

I have pasted the C# code into the telerik converter, and the converted code is:

```
Private Shared Function BuildTree(ByVal items As List(Of Category)) As IEnumerable(Of Category)
    items.ForEach(Function(i) CSharpImpl.__Assign(i.Categories, items.Where(Function(ch) ch.ParentId = i.Id).ToList()))
    Return items.Where(Function(i) i.ParentId Is Nothing).ToList()
End Function

Private Class CSharpImpl
    <Obsolete("Please refactor calling code to use normal Visual Basic assignment")>
    Shared Function __Assign(Of T)(ByRef target As T, value As T) As T
        target = value
        Return value
    End Function
End Class
```

It uses an helper class to solve this issue, but suggests a refactor to avoid this.

Hence the questions:

- **Is there a general way to disambiguate `equality =` and `assignment =` in VB.NET, without resorting to an helper class and a specific function to assignement**
- **In this specific case, is there a simple refactor I can use to get rid of the issue?**

Comment: Use `Return ch.ParentNodeName = n.Name` to resolve the ambiguity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because of VB.Net distinction between functions and subroutines.

Instead of

```
nodes.ForEach(Function(n) n.Children = nodes.Where(Function(ch) ch.ParentNodeName = n.Name).ToList)
```

use

```
nodes.ForEach(Sub(n) n.Children = nodes.Where(Function(ch) ch.ParentNodeName = n.Name).ToList)
```

When you use `Function`, the lambda expression is expected to return a value; and in your case it looks like it wants to return a boolean.

But you want to use a lambda expression that does not return anything (in your case, you want an assignment), you have to use `Sub`.

Comment: This is partly because in VB, assignment is a statement, not an expression (as distinct from C-heritage languages).  So if you use `=` in an expression context, it will necessarily be interpreted as the equality comparison operator, since it can't be an assignment.